# Can someone give me more info on what the The role and aria-* HTML5 attributes do?

Tags: html

I want to know what the role and aria-* attributes are for in HTML5. Thanks.

Comment: Google: http://standardssuck.org/aria-in-html5
and http://www.accessibleculture.org/research/html5-aria/

Answer (score 0):

ARIA is an acronym for Accessible Rich Internet Application. The HTML5 attribute is a mapping of the W3C WAI-ARIA spec to HTML5. It's purpose is to aid assistive technologies -- like screen readers for blind users -- understand web applications and widgets. It's especially of importance in AJAX style interactions.

For example: A HTML/CSS widget may be made entirely of DIVs and be dynamically updated. Because the Semantics of HTML are not sufficient to describe rich applications, the aria attributes help to inform assistive technologies of their purpose and any dynamic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The different components that you create can each have a single "role" which attempts to describe what the component is and does.

There are a bunch of different roles. The roles fall into two categories: "abstract" roles which are used for discussion, and "actual" roles that you use.

Each role has to include some different "aria*" attributes. These attributes describe the current state of the widget, and they change as the widget changes.

For example, imagine you want to create a slider widget out of a bunch of divs and javascript. The slider widget's abstract role is "range" because it represents a possible range of values. It's actual role that you'll use in code is "slider". The different aria attributes that describe the slider that you need to use are "aria-valuenow, aria-valuemax, aria-valuemin".

I used this page: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#slider
It is really helpful, you can click on an abstract role and see all of the subroles that belong to it. For each role, it gives you a list of the required aria- attributes.